# A list that is not a list yet

Tags: python, list

How can I make `{'s': 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p': 'type', 'o': 'term1_course'}` a list in python 3.7? The ':' should be replaced by ','.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show any research you have done so far?

Comment: Hello @kNiEsSoKk. Please add the required Output and also code of what you have tried and what's not working.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want the output to be and any code that you have tried already? Converting a dictionary to list should be simple.

Comment: thanks Scotty, that solved my problem! Did not know this was called a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution converts every `key` and `value` in your dict into one list.

```
d = {'s': 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p': 'type', 'o': 'term1_course'}
mylist = []
for k, v in d.items():
    mylist.append(k)
    mylist.append(v)

print(mylist)
```

Yields:
`['s', 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p', 'type', 'o', 'term1_course']`

Which equates to your request of replacing `:` with `,`

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is a dictionary. A dictionary is a collection of key value pairs, where the thing on the left of the `:` is the key, and the thing on the right is the value.

To create a list that contains the keys and values of the dictionary you can do something like this:

```
dict = {
  's': 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 
  'p': 'type', 
  'o': 'term1_course'
}

list = []

for key in dict.keys():
    value = dict[key]
    list.append(key)
    list.append(value)
```

After this, `list` will be `['s', 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p', 'type', 'o', 'term1_course']`

Answer (score 0):

> Iterate over the dict and extend to a list as follows:

```
mydict = {'s': 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p': 'type', 'o': 'term1_course'}
mylist = []
for x in mydict.items():
    mylist.extend(x)
```

> Output
>   ['o', 'term1_course', 's', 'http://webprotege.stanford.edu/INFOMDM', 'p', 'type']